# How do you call the "act" of saving information?

Tags: phrase-request, gerunds, legalese

There is a way of saying things with verbs like "Save data" or "clean room" or "Backup file". They have their counterparts like

Clean room --> Room Cleaning

Backup file --> File Backup

Save Data --->  ?????

What would be the counterpart for "save ...data"   or "Save information"?

(By counterpart I mean a noun that designate the process that is being carried out)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is ***data storage***, but that typically pertains to methods used to store information or data in a persistent manner. I don't think there is an equivalent phrase for ***saving data*** other than simply saying ***saving***.

However, in the world of databases, they often use the term [***commit***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_(data_management)) when talking about saving changes that have been made during the data modification process. But that's probably not exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Two common choices:

- "Saving data" is a gerund.
- "[Data retention](https://infogalactic.com/info/Data_retention)" is a noun phrase, with a technical (and legal) meaning.

Answer (score 0):

> Clean room --> Room Cleaning
>
> Backup file --> File Backup
>
> Save Data ---> **Saved Data**

If the context is programming/software development, "stored data" may be slightly better.

If you really mean "Save Data to File" (based on "Backup File" previously) then "Saved File" or just plain "File" would work.

Comment: I was refering to the process not to the product

Comment: In a software development context, it's *writing*.  To an end user, *data saving* is probably the best you can do.